# ODE45 and time interval

Tags: matlab

`ODE45` function in matlab takes argument:

```
(function,[tinitial tfinal],yinitial)
```

But here, I believe, the span of time is predetermined. How can I assign a vector for it? I mean how do I solve the ODE for the domain `1:0.1:5`?

Thank You.

Comment: The span is indeed adaptive and depends on the relative error you require on the solution. You get the time grid as a returned vector from the call of ode45. You can anyway pass a time vector to have the solution in that very same vector.

Comment: @Acorbe Could you bother to elaborate what you mean by "indeed adaptive and depends on the relative error"? Do you mean it is not possible for me to use ODE45 to evaluate for the time vector 1:0.1:5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the values at specified points in time, simply go:

```
tspan = 1:0.1:5
[T Y] = ode45(odefun, tspan, y0)
```

`T` should be the same as `tspan`, and `Y` will be the corresponding values for each point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the following vector for time span,and this way, you are saying  to ode45 that you want the solution at specific time points (here , every 0.001)

```
tspan = ti:0.001:tf;
```

Output vectors ( T, X ) will have as many steps as the tspan vector has.

(But if you mean that you want the solver to take predetermined and constant steps for solving the equation , you can't do that.)